# XHR Get Request not passing Google Chromestore Checks

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

We've built a very lightweight simple Chrome extension for our customers, its private and won't be made publicly available but due to restrictions by Google now needs to at least exist privately on their store.

The idea of the extension is to automatically track cashback opportunities for our clients computers. It does this by checking each new URL they visit just once against our API - if its not a shopping site that exists (eg Facebook or Google) then storage makes sure that URL is never checked again, if it is, then its checked only once in a 24 hour period and the URL returned by the API is visited with an AJAX GET Request.

The get request loads the URL via the cashback site so it sets the correct cookies for the user automatically, in the background, without disrupting the users browsing session.

The extension though whilst accepted by Apple and Mozilla for Firefox and Safari is being rejected by Google and it appears to be due to our XHR request - though they sent the same generic rejection request and it appears its being rejected via an automatic check - it appears whats being flagged up is that the GET request *could* be request external javascript (eg malicious stuff) from 3rd parties and of course all code (and quite rightly) needs to be within the extension itself.

They provide examples of using cross-origin calls on their site here https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr

As we only need to set the cookies from the URL we visit, would there be anyway to filter the get request to abide by their security rules and instead of just downloading everything from the URL we'd block downloading external javascript libraries etc?

This is well beyond my realms of coding here so i'm more interested if anyone could think of a way we COULD do this that would pass Google's checks - ultimately the AJAX request we do just loads the website they are already on, but as its going via a tracking company to set the cookie it will of course call on a couple of simple redirects first usually to set the session ID. If its possible for us to still use this data whilst making it pass Google checks, i'm not sure.

Here is a snippet of current XHR related code

```
   kango.xhr.send(details, function(data) {
    if (data.status == 200 && data.response != null) {
        var text = data.response;
        console.log(window.location.href);
        kango.console.log("THE RESPONSE URL: " + text);
        var affilDetails = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: text,
            async: true,
            contentType: 'text'
        };
```

and
    `kango.xhr.send(affilDetails, function (afilData) {
    console.log(thisDomain + " expire updated to " + new Date(expireshort));
                    if (afilData.status == 200 && afilData.response != null) {
                        kango.storage.setItem(thisDomain,expireshort);
                        console.log("RESPONSE URL HAS BEEN VISITED VIA AJAX.");`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about (undisclosed) third-party policy.

Comment: XHR in extensions is absolutely fine by CWS standards. In fact, unlike Mozilla there's no explicit rejection of code loading from elsewhere. If you weren't given a reason that's quite a jump to think that is the reason. Now, important questions though: 1) did you modify CSP? 2) is the XHR origin unencrypted HTTP?

Comment: Well the generic reasoning e-mail is

To have your item reinstated, please make any necessary changes to ensure:

`All of the files and code are included in the item’s package.
All code inside the package is human readable (no obfuscated or minified code).
Avoid requesting or executing remotely hosted code (including by referencing remote javascript files or executing code obtained by XHR requests).`

The only thing we do is the Ajax get request that could possibly be considered any of those - it could look like we're trying to pull in code from an external source (which we're not)

Comment: The XHR is any URL the API spits out, so of course it'll be plain HTTP requests or anything else - all its doing is trying to load the affiliate URL to set the tracking session for that store.

Comment: You haven't answered whether you modified `content_security_policy`.

Comment: We used Kango so by default it was already done to..

`"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'", 
    "permissions": [
        "tabs", 
        "http://*/*", 
        "https://*/*", 
        "contextMenus", 
        "webNavigation"
    ]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112504/discussion-between-xan-and-danny-shepherd).